# Exporting SQLite database from the phone

Tags: android, sqlite

There is a simple way to export the databse from developed app in eclipse DMS section. However, is there a simple way to export database from the app which is installed on the device already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only if you write it. You are welcome to add options to your application for copying the database file to external storage. This might be part of a backup-and-restore feature. Just make sure your database is closed while this is going on.

Comment: @Xylian: Well, that example exports it as an XML file. You're welcome to do that if you want. I just meant to copy the SQLite database file itself to external storage, so you can examine it using SQLite Manager or your favorite other SQLite client.

Comment: that's what I actually need. Gotta find some tutorial for that